# How can I do this in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

This operation I was made in inkscape. Can I repeat it in AI?

[image: points transformation]

Comment: Uhm.. select the anchor points and use the Free Transform tool.

Answer (score 1):

Use the scale tool! (A) to use direct selection to select the anchor points you want to scale then (S) to open the scale tool to do exactly that thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the path key you want to edit. And then use **Free Transform Tool** (E) to do that operation. To select the path key, use **Direct Selection Tool** (A).

Comment: scale tool is better in many ways.